# How to bundle Cypress test suites as an executable .exe, using esbuild and pkg?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cypress, esbuild

I have some Cypress tests. I need to create an .exe file so that anyone who wants to run the tests can just double-click the .exe - no technical knowledge needed.

The tests run against a QA environment in the cloud: my project/repo does not contain any of the code under test, just a `/cypress` folder with all the usual Cypress stuff in it. So I don't need to worry about having the .exe spin up the app to to be tested.

Double-clicking the .exe should open Terminal (or Powershell), where the user is prompted to enter some options for how the tests should be run.

I don't think Cypress was ever intended to be run as an .exe, so there's not a lot online about how to do it.

My current approach is:

1. Create an entrypoint `index.mjs` file that prompts the user for test run options
2. Use Cypress' [Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api) to conditionally run/open Cypress, based on the user's input
3. Use [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/getting-started/) to bundle everything into a single index.js file
4. Use [pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg#readme) to create an .exe

Steps 1 and 2 were easy enough, and `node index.mjs` is working exactly as it should.

I've also managed to get step 3 working, so `node dist/index.js` (running the bundled file) runs the same as `node index.mjs`, as long as it is run from the project root directory (because it needs to find `node_modules/cypress`).

However, I'm having problems with step 4. I can successfully create an .exe file that I can run from anywhere on my computer. When it runs, it opens Terminal and behaves exactly the same as `node index.mjs`... except that once the Cypress app opens, none of my test specs are listed.

I can't wrap my head around how to get the actual test code (ie everything in the `/cypress/e2e` and `/cypress/support` directories) included in the .exe

(Assume all code samples below have been abbreviated for brevity)

```
// File structure
.
├── cypress
│   ├── e2e
│   ├── screenshots
│   ├── support
│   ├── videos
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── dist
│   └── index.js
├── node_modules
├── build.mjs
├── index.mjs
├── cypress.config.ts
├── package.json
└── .eslintrc.js
```

```json
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start:node": "node index.mjs",
    "cypress:open": "npx cypress open",
    "cypress:run": "npx cypress run",
    "build": "node build.mjs",
    "package": "pkg ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "^2.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.1.0",
    "cypress": "^12.17.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "envsafe": "^2.0.3",
    "esbuild": "^0.19.2",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "pkg": "^5.8.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "inquirer": "^9.2.10",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  }
}
```

```js
// Entrypoint file - index.mjs

import inquirer from "inquirer";
import cypress from "cypress";

const runTypeQuestion = { // ...};
const brokerQuestion = { // ...};

const runTests = async () => {
  const answers = await inquirer.prompt([brokerQuestion, runTypeQuestion]);
  const runType = answers[RUN_TYPE_QN];
  const broker = answers[BROKER_QN];

  if (runType === RUN_TYPE_RUN) {
    cypress.run();
  } else if (runType === RUN_TYPE_OPEN) {
    cypress.open()
  } else {
    console.error("Invalid run type");
  }
};

const main = async () => {
  await runTests()
};

export default main();
```

```
// build.mjs
import * as esbuild from 'esbuild';

const onCypressPlugin = {
  name: 'cypress-plugin',
  setup: (build) => {
    build.onResolve({ filter: /cypress/ }, args => {
      return { path: args.path, external: true }
    })
  }
}

const build = async () => {
  const { errors, warnings, metafile } = await esbuild.build({
    entryPoints: ['index.mjs'],
    bundle: true,
    platform: 'node',
    outdir: 'dist',
    metafile: true,
    define: {
      'import.meta.url': '__dirname'
    },
    plugins: [onCypressPlugin]
  });

  // ...
};

void build();
```

```
// cypress.config.ts

import cypress from 'cypress';
import 'dotenv/config';
import { str, envsafe } from 'envsafe';
import createBundler from '@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor';

const { defineConfig } = cypress;

export const env = envsafe({
  // ...
});

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on) {
      on('file:preprocessor', createBundler());
    },
  },
  env: {
    // ...
  },
});
```

How can I get the files in the `./cypress` folder included in the .exe?